# How to Disable a AutoCompleteTextField in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, autocomplete, disabled-input

I am developing a Flutter app that has a AutoCompleteTextField in it. I want to enable it in insert mode and disable it in update mode. How can i do it?
This is my code for AutoCompleteTextField. It works absolutely fine but i want to disable it in update mode or based on any condition.

```
                  Expanded(
                    child:  AutoCompleteTextField(
                      controller: input_controller,
                      suggestions: input_list,
                      clearOnSubmit: false,
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10,0,10,0),

                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                        ),
                        
                        hintText: 'INPUT',
                        labelText: 'INPUT',
                      ),
                      itemFilter: (item,query){
                        return item.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase());
                      },
                      itemSorter: (a, b){
                        return a.compareTo(b);
                      },
                      itemSubmitted: (item){
                        input_controller.text = item;
                      },
                      itemBuilder: (context,item){
                        return Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(item),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: Could you add a Minimal Working Example?

Comment: Do you mean auto-correct ? Otherwise can you give use a example of your code about your TextField

Comment: @Thierry Yeah Sure.

Comment: This is not a **working** example. It would be easier to provide a trargeted answer with a complete yet minimal sample. How do you make the difference between INSERT and UPDATE modes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you differentiate between INSERT and UPDATE mode in your application. But maybe you can find a way to do something like this:

```dart
Expanded(
  child: isInsertMode 
      ? AutoCompleteTextField(...)
      : TextFormField(...)
),
```